# Auto populate new sheet with data

Tags: excel, vba

I tried looking at other similiar questions and solutions but as an Excel beginner I couldn't quite figure it out.

So I have the following macro:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

On Error Resume Next

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B46:B99")) Is Nothing Then

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LT").Copy _
 After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)



End If 
End Sub
```

It opens a new sheet in the same workbook and I'd need to auto populate certain cells with data from the main sheet. Main sheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU5SC.jpg new sheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/drK6d.jpg . The cells I need copied are in red.

Thanks in advance for any help! Really new to all this..

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't specify which value(s) you need to pull from the main sheet I can't get too specific, but in general there are three approaches to take.

1) If the data is in contiguous range(s) of cells on both sheets, you can just copy the data from the main sheet after creating the new sheet, and then paste the values to the correct target range

2) If the data isn't contiguous on both sheets, then your next best option would be to have the value for each target cell set based on the value of the corresponding cell on the main page. Ex: To set A2 on Sheet2 to the value of B4 on Sheet1 you would use `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").value`

3) This one also works if the data isn't contiguous, but gets to be troublesome if there are more than ~5 values to copy. You can create an appropriate variable (string for text, long/int for numbers, etc.), set that before creating the new sheet, and then use them to set the appropriate cells once the new sheet is created.